# ios5 - "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when clicking button

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, exc-bad-access

I am a total beginner to Objective C.

Currently I try to display a view in my main window. This view contains a button. For some reason by clicking this button xcode throws an error.

Hopefully you can help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    BtnView *btn = [[BtnView alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:btn.view];        
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

The viewController of my button view has an action for recognizing a  touch up event
h file:

```
- (IBAction)touched:(id)sender;
```

and in the m file

```
- (IBAction)touched:(id)sender {
    //actions ...
}
```

By touching the button I get the following error:

[image]
Whats wrong?

m file:

[image]

h file:
[image]

Comment: Can you add code for BtnView class as well?

Comment: post code from your BtnView.m and BtnView.h

Comment: hehe guys I am trying to... editor in here is a bit hard to handle

Comment: @mogio how do add your button? i mean, the actual button you pressed. how do you create it?

Comment: I dragged it onto the view of the xib. From the object library.

Comment: Is something wrong in the way I show the view within my window ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have ARC enabled for this project.

When you return from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` the object assigned to `btn` will be released since you assign it to a local variable that is only defined within that method.  Make `BtnView *btn` a `strong` property of your class and it should stay around to handle the button presses.  (Remember to use `self.btn` in references to it.)

(But, I'm curious, why not just put the button on your main view in the first place and then not worry about an extra controller and subviews?)

Comment: Oh thank you Phillip !... of course... I did not think at this.. .but you are right... maybe I better work without ARC... guess there are hundreds of possible situations this kind of problem can occur.

Comment: because I am trying to understand the whole viewController thing... appart from that .. .I would separate code from view anyway... as this is the mvc way I learned in other languages

Comment: The usual pattern for view controllers is that they are made part of a controller hierarchy that retains them while they are in use (push, modal, containers...) and that all works fine with ARC.  Using a controller's view without actually making the controller part of that chain is a bit different from their intended use and therefore needs different treatment in order to work.

Comment: I will definitely look more into the correct use of ARC. To be earnest a friend meant it is a great way to program, but I should learn the old clean way first, so I know more whats going up behind the scenes.

Comment: oh Phillip one question regarding ARC. I assume there are situations when you have to dynamically create UI Elements that can not be defined as strong properties as they would be created on the fly. Does it make sense to create some kind of strong property of type Array that holds references to ensure the are not removed by the ARC mechanism?

Comment: Yes, for example your `btn.view` is placed into a subview array and is retained there until the owning view is unloaded or otherwise disposed of.  That's not essentially different from on-the-fly object creation.

Comment: cool. I just tried this with an an NSMutableDictionary Class which is a singleton. In combination with NSNotifications ... this seems like a lot of fun :) Some kind of global object handler...

Comment: Sounds like you're half-way to inventing the Windows Registry.  :)

Comment: hmmmm in this case I better stop ;) my plan is not to create spaghetti code... but its a nice way to have a controller for the main views that controls the view in and outs by working together with an event message system.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)touched
```

try without using sender

Answer (score 0):

In .xib file, you can hook up the button to file's owner.

1) Right Click on button. Then one window will be appeared. You can see `Touch Up Inside` in that window and click on small circle and drag to file's owner and connect to `touched`. I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: How did you create button either programmatically or drag the button to .xib?

Comment: Did you connect as what i wrote?

Comment: have a look... it is such a small file.. no custom code at all

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why do you need the whole UIViewController to be a button? The conventional way to do this would be to have the UIViewController as a controller and than put a UIButton as a subview to its view in the viewDidLoad method, hook it up to the desired methods and even have it across the whole screen if you need. In case you need to customize the appearance, you can do that with UIButton too.

Comment: it was just a learning project. I need to learn how I load views, windows etc. Also the differences between windows and views aren't clear to me so far. I am really at the start